# Finding the difference between current time and last updated time on Parse backend

Tags: java, date, time, parse-platform, simpledateformat

I'm trying to write a Java script that computes the time difference between the current date and the last updated time stored on our Parse backend. Can anyone help me spot the bug in my code? You'd think this isn't so bad, but I've looked on Stack Overflow for hours to no avail.

```
//Create a date formatter.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'LLL'Z'");
//Create a date object for today's date.
        Date currentDate=new Date();
//Create a string for the date from parse.
        String parseTime = singleClaim.getString("updatedAt");
//Create a string for the current date.
        String currentTime=currentDate.toString();
//Initialize the date object for the updatedAt time on Parse.
        Date parseDate = null;
//Initialize the date object for the current time.
        Date FormattedCurrentDate = null;
        try {
//Here, we convert the parseTime string into a date object and format it.
            parseDate = formatter.parse(parseTime);
//Here, we convert the currentTime string into a date object and format it.
            FormattedCurrentDate = formatter.parse(currentTime);
} 

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

   //Get the time difference from the current date versus the date on Parse.
        long difference = FormattedCurrentDate.getTime()-parseDate.getTime();
```

Comment: Can you give example of output ?

Comment: Why you covert currentDate to string and parse it again?

Comment: Have you tried Joda-Time or Java 8's Time API?

Comment: I want to determine if the difference in time between the current time and the last updated time on Parse is less than 24 hours. That's the goal.

Comment: millisecond arithmetic is full of issues, lets not even get started with time zones.  Use an appropriate API which can take care of these issues for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call toString() to convert Date to String. And why you convert currentTime to String and later parse it to a date? This makes no sence.

```
//Create a date formatter.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'LLL'Z'");
//Create a date object for today's date.
        Date currentDate=new Date();
//Create a string for the date from parse.
        String parseTime = singleClaim.getString("updatedAt");
//Create a string for the current date.
        String currentTime=currentDate.toString();
//Initialize the date object for the updatedAt time on Parse.
        Date parseDate = null;
        try {
//Here, we convert the parseTime string into a date object and format it.
            parseDate = formatter.parse(parseTime);
} 

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

   //Get the time difference from the current date versus the date on Parse.
        long difference = currentDate.getTime()-parseDate.getTime();
```

Comment: @Downvoter please explain!

Comment: Didn't dv but I'd guess this should be a simple comment.

Comment: @Filburt no that is the solution. Not a comment

Comment: @Jens I'll restore balance to the universe. Your answer is correct, so I have no idea why you got downvoted.

Comment: @Jens, but doesn't currentDate need to be formatted according to the formatter to be able to subtract ParseDate from it?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen That is the problem in stackoverflow. You can downvote and nobody knows why.

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer No you substract the time in milliseconds. which be an long value. The format is only a representation. That has nothing to do with the internal format of the date.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of these two lines is probably causing your issue:

```
String currentTime=currentDate.toString();
// ...
FormattedCurrentDate = formatter.parse(currentTime);
```

The `currentTime` variable does not contain a properly formatting string that can be comsumed by your formatter.

I also see no need to create such a string, you could just do it as follows:

```
long difference = currentDate.getTime() - parseDate.getTime();
```

---

If you absolutely insist on making a round trip from date to string and back, you would have to create your `currentTime` string as follows:

```
currentTime = formatter.format(currentDate);
```

Comment: but doesn't currentDate need to be formatted according to the formatter to be able to subtract parseDate from it?

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer In Java a `Date` is just a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, it has not internal format of it's own..